# Scrolling issue with Polidea Zoomview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, zooming, pinchzoom

I'm a newbie android developer and having some troubles in implementing Polidea ZoomView. I want to create a zoomable listview. I tried [this](https://github.com/Xjasz/AndroidZoomableViewGroup/blob/master/ZoomListView.java)   library from github. But there are few issues with this library. The issue is on zooming via pinch the listview always scroll from top left side of the container.
Then I used this [Polidea Zoomview](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view) library. Its pretty good. I inserted my listview inside the container of the Polidea Zoomview. The first issue that I faced with previous library was gone. But then I noticed that Listview is not scrolling vertically after zooming. Any suggestion or fixes?